# Are these corrections correct with respect to possessive noun?

Tags: sentence-construction, possessives

> My grandmother, **whose 75**, still goes swimming every day. *(original)*
>   My grandmother, **who is 75**, still goes swimming every day. *(correction)*
>
> We have a dog **which** name is Groucho.  *(original)*
>   We have a dog, **whose** name is Groucho. *(correction)*

Comment: Not quite correct. The last sentence should not have a comma in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both of the corrections are correct.

We use *whose* like this:

> My grandmother, **whose** dog is named "Groucho", still goes swimming every day.

and we use *who is* like this:

> Groucho, **who is** my grandmother's dog, goes swimming every day.

In sentences like,

> We have a dog which/whose name is Groucho

Your teacher or book wants to teach that we should use *whose* to stand for people, animals, and things. If we want to use a pronoun to stand for a person, however, we should not use *which.*

> We have a horse **whose** name is "Star."
>
> My brother build a barn, **which** is Star's home.

Note that *who's* is the contraction for *who is,* so we could also use *Groucho, who's my grandmother's dog ....*

Comment: +1 But I suspect OP's real confusion is with *whose / who's*.